# Node.js NOT-XOR optimization

Tags: javascript, node.js, expression

I've been looking for a way to micro-optimize the following logical expression in Node.js, but I failed to find any better method of implementing it:

Suppose A and B vars, both are booleans (results of complex methods/expressions):

```
    if ( (A && B) || (!A && !B) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

    //Obviously the returns are redundant in this case.
```

The truth table for this expression is:

```
    ╔════╦═══════╦═══════╗
    ║    ║   A   ║  !A   ║
    ╠════╬═══════╬═══════╣
    ║ B  ║ true  ║ false ║
    ╠════╬═══════╬═══════╣
    ║ !B ║ false ║ true  ║
    ╚════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Thanks from ahead!

Comment: `return !!(A && B || !A && !B));` - and if you know they're `boolean` you can leave off the `!!`

Comment: ... actually if you know they're boolean, `return A === B;` :)

Comment: @Pointy, huh! I can't believe I oversaw this. That's what was under my nose for days. :)
Why don't you post it as an answer so I can accept? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression is equivalent:

```
return A === B;
```